# I cannot use NetLimiter in API on C#

Tags: c#, .net

[image]

I'm creating a program that will control the Netlimiter application using API, though I already allow ""...but it keeps telling that error what is the problem.can anyone help?

Comment: Never heard of this NetLimiter program before.  Have a link?

Comment: @Ben: http://www.netlimiter.com/devzone.php

Comment: It looks like you haven't set `AllowAPI` to `true` in the xml file.  That website says that you must stop the service before editing the settings file.

Comment: @Ben: I already set  to true sir....but keeps telling that error.

Comment: @Sheng: Did restart the service?  Actually according to the webpage, a restart may not be enough.  You have to stop it, make the change, then start it.

Comment: I've already done sir, do you know vshost.exe sir???how to disable this??

Comment: There's an option "Use VS hosting process" under your C# project settings (I think in the debug section), turn that off and vshost.exe won't appear any more.