# How can I embed NetLimiter in my application

Tags: winapi, qos

I have a C# client application that connects to multiple servers. I noticed that it is necessary to use [NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/) activated rules in order to make my client connect correctly **with higher priority** when there is so many traffic on the client computer.

I did not find any documents about how can I embed and make rules programmatically in this application. However, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283674/i-cannot-use-netlimiter-in-api-on-c-sharp) that someone tried to use Netlimiter API but failed.

I read somewhere that I can write my own application that uses TC API of the Windows in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374094(v=vs.85).aspx) and **mark DSCP** to make priorities. But I reached to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207124/how-to-prioritise-packets-using-traffic-control-tc-api-in-windows) problem before setting flow options of my C# application.

Please guide me with this issue.

Comment: If you want to programmatically change how NetLimiter treats a program, you need to use the NetLimiter API.  If NetLimiter is throwing errors, then you need to a) consult the NetLimiter  documentation, and/r b) open a support call with NetLimiter.

Comment: @paulsm4 where can I find the API? did not find any on its website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625065832/http://netlimiter.com/devzone.php). `Connect()` and `SetRule()` are the only APIs available.

NetLimiter seems to be a COM object, so to use it from C# you need something like this:

```
dynamic myownlimiter = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NetLimiter.VirtualClient"));
myownlimiter.Connect("host", "port");
```

and then use `SetRule()` as described in the first link.

Comment: `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NetLimiter.VirtualClient")` returns null

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee the authors seem to have altered the class name. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660319/where-can-i-find-all-of-the-com-objects-that-can-be-created-in-powershell) to list all COM object names in your system and find the appropriate one.